# Observable not displaying data in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, rest, angular, observable

I need to make a RESTful call and watch for changes using Angular 2 (the values should be updated every time it changes in the API).

In my service, I've added an `Observable` to get the data from the API:

```
getData(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

I call that in my `constructor` to update `list: any = [];`:

```
constructor(http: Http) {
  this.list = this.getData();
}
```

Then, in my HTML, I'm trying to display that data using `ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list | async">
  <h1>{{item.value}}</h1>
</div>
```

However, any data is being displayed. If I try to `console.log(res)` in `map`, I also don't get anything. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** After following Ivaro's suggestion, I'm getting an error with the `AsyncPipe`. However, if I remove it, how can I get the data to be updated when the API changes? I was using `Observal.interval` before, but I didn't want to call the API at a defined interval. I wanted it to watch for changes and update accordingly.

Here's my data structure, btw:

```
[{
  "name": "apple",
  "value" 2
}, {
  "name": "banana",
  "value" 10
}]
```

Comment: `return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => {return res.json();});`

Comment: And cause you're passing an Observable of a list and not the list itself, in you constructor:  `this.getData().subscribe(response => { this.list = response; });`

Comment: in your constructor `this.list = this.getData();` but you are using `let item of service.list`  where are you defining `this.service`?

Comment: @echonax yes, it's defined because I'm just calling that service from another component.

Comment: I tried @Ivaro18 suggestion and I'm getting `Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`.

Comment: Remove `| async` from your html

Comment: Yeah, but how can I get the data to be updated when the API changes? I was using `Observal.interval` before, but I didn't want to call the API at a defined interval. I wanted it to watch for changes and update accordingly.

Comment: That seems a lot like [the example in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#async-pipe), I don't see why it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

An observable must be subscribed. Since it is asynchronous, it returns undefined, and that is what is being assigned to `this.list` in your code.
Instead subscribe:

```
constructor(http: Http) {
  this.getData().subscribe(
        res => this.list = res,
        err = > console.log(err) /*handle error*/
    );
}
```

#### Edit:

For the `| async` pipe to work, use `(list | async)`  (this doesn't need any subscription from observable as the `async` pipe internally subscribes)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (list | async)">
  <h1>{{item.value}}</h1>
</div>
```

The parentheses are required since execution happens from left to right and `let item of list` will be executed, which doesn't have required data.
So, `( list | async )`  makes it have proper value in `list`.

Comment: But then you're assigning the result to `this.list`, not the observable, and the `| async` pipe behaviour won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for is commonly called [Observable Data Services](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services).